# Use an assert statement in the @Before method of a JUnit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, annotations

Should I use assert statements (`assertEquals`,...) in the `@Before` method of a JUnit test?

If the assertion fails, all tests will fail, so it behaves exactly how I want, but I'm not convinced this is a good idea as the `@Before`-annotated method is not a test.

Comment: I would say no as that method should be used to set up items that are required for the each test.

Comment: If the setup of the test fails, and as a result none of the other tests will succeed, why continue executing the tests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the [Assume](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html) mechanism would be more appropriate.

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions
> in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the
> code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information. The
> default JUnit runner treats tests with failing assumptions as ignored.
> Custom runners may behave differently.

That perhaps seems more intuitive, since you're testing a test precondition before actually executing each test. Note the reference above to custom runners performing differently, and you could amend a runner to fail rather than silently ignore the test.

Comment: I disagree. I believe the assume will silently skip all tests rather than failing them as is the desired result.

Comment: Note the last sentence of the quote. A custom runner can be created to fail for each failed assumption

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't see any problem with it. If the desired is for all tests to fail is some precondition is not met, that meets the requirement. My only thought here is that you should be verifying preconditions not doing testing of the code under test. Otherwise it would seem to be misleading and I would suggest putting the condition in a method that is called from each test.